# Power saving for raspberry pi2 model B

Tags: usb, power, hub

I have a raspberry pi 2 Model B and I want to disable the power to ethernet and USB hub port, I try using hub ctrl. c command, and it doesn't work.

Is this happening because of the limitation of the hardware? Will this be working on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

Actually, I want to control the USB port. Since there are four USB ports on my raspberry pi 2 model B, I want to know If it is possible to turn off the power of USB ports with software, not with hardware.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.*

Comment: Hello I want to control the USB port. Since there are four USB ports on my raspberry pi 2 model B, I want to know If it is possible to turn off the power of USB ports with software, not with hardware.

Answer (score 3):

### Installation

You can block the power of all USB ports by the following procedure.

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev git
```

Get the required source:

```
git clone https://github.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c
```

Go to the new directory by `cd hub-ctrl.c` and install it:

```
gcc -o hub-ctrl hub-ctrl.c -lusb
```

---

### Usage

Turn off Ethernet Port:

```
sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 1 -p 0
```

Turn on Ethernet Port:

```
sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 1 -p 1
```

Turn off all USB Ports:

```
sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 2 -p 0
```

Turn on all USB Ports:

```
sudo ./hub-ctrl -h 0 -P 2 -p 1
```

---

> Will this be working on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

Yes, you can use it on Raspberry Pi 3B. The Raspberry Pi 2 has this feature to cut/block the power of USB ports. If this procedure doesn't work, you accomplish it by [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl). It supports Raspberry Pi models B+, 2B, 3B, 3B+, and 4B.
Another approach is [binding/unbinding](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/linux/learning-how-to-disable-specific-usb-devices-by-their-ports-in-linux/1645) the individual post but not work on all types of connected devices.

---

***References:***

- [How to disable specific USB devices by their ports](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/linux/learning-how-to-disable-specific-usb-devices-by-their-ports-in-linux/1645)
- [GitHub - uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl)
- [GitHub - hub-ctrl.c](https://github.com/codazoda/hub-ctrl.c)
- [How to power off Raspberry Pi 3 USB or Ethernet ports](http://embeddedapocalypse.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-power-off-raspberry-pi-3-usb-or.html)
- [How can I cut power coming out of the Pi's USB ports?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/how-can-i-cut-power-coming-out-of-the-pis-usb-ports)