# Can you damage the pi's USB controller by constantly applying and removing power to it?

Tags: usb, usb-power

I have a pair of USB powered fans. I currently have them connected to a Raspberry Pi 3b+ via one of the USB-A connectors, drawing power from the pi.

I have two cron jobs set on the pi - one that disables power to the USB controller every even minute, and then one that re-enables power every odd minute. This effectively turns the RPi into a fan controller. This allows the fans to run in my greenhouse to cycle air, but doesn't keep them running so much that they dry everything out.

I am using `uhubctl` as described in one of the answers to this question:

[How can I cut power coming out of the Pi's USB ports?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/how-can-i-cut-power-coming-out-of-the-pis-usb-ports)

My concern is, I am basically adding and removing power to the USB controller every minute of every day. Will this eventually cause damage to the USB controller? Can it cause damage over time?

Comment: No idea.  Not sure that this is Pi specific.

Comment: yes, everything man made fails over a span of a few million years

Comment: @joan it's specifically about a RPi 3b+ USB controller. I'm not asking about USB controllers in a general sense.