# Shut down standalone pi without access

Tags: sd-card, shutdown

I'm working on getting a pi connected to my wifi network (my first attempt failed). I don't have ethernet access, nor do I have a monitor and keyboard.

When pulling the plug, I'm corrupting the filesystem such that I can't mount it to make edits on my laptop.

Is there a safe way to shut it down? Do I need to use a serial console? I don't want to have to re-image it every time I mess up.

Comment: Does this help [Shutdown Button](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24597/external-shutdown-properly-button)

Comment: Just pulling the plug is not recommended, but it should not cause you problems every time you do it.  Better to shutdown properly, but sometimes you just have to pull the plug.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect a pushbutton to Pi to safely shutdown.

I use a button connected to pins 39, 40 in conjunction with the following script when I am without keyboard or `ssh` access to safely shutdown.

[How to safely switch off the Raspberry Pi?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42945/8697)