# is it possible for the raspberry pi 2 to disable usb interface rx and tx?

Tags: usb, hardware, usb-power

I was thinking of a program that would grant access to the raspberry pi usb port if the user was authorized and disable it if not. Most of the links I found are regarding the usb port supply, while it is conducive i think it is much safer if the transmit and receive pin at the usb port can be toggled. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Will these users have physical access to the Pi, its' connected devices or the SD card?

Comment: We're not sure yet if it can be done. There's some stuff that's still not released by Broadcom.

Comment: I was working with a prototype of a security device, and I would like the firmware to decide for itself if it would allow the use of usb port accord to its conditions and i got an idea of using external transistors/gates to switch rx/tx, but i was just trying to find a shorter way around without using my gpio

Answer (score 4):

Just like this [question/answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/turning-on-and-off-a-3g-or-any-usb-port) suggests, there is no way to cut the power or the TX/RX on the USB ports with just software. You will need to add a transistor and do some fancy wiring, which is all described in the answer to that question.